# Why OSM doesn't provide administrative division for national parks?

Tags: openstreetmap

I noticed that for many national parks OSM doesn't provide administrative division (state, province) where they belong to (only country). Some examples:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=2597516462
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=145053908

Meanwhile for some others it is specified:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=145091198

Any idea why? And how can I figure out where they belong to using OSM data?

Comment: There is an open data project to submit boundaries if you want to explore this. https://github.com/OpenBounds

Answer (score 3):

OSM is made by people like me and you. There is no global committee that normalises and standardises everything.

I guess that the implicite topology of the polygons allows you to query against intersecting polygons with admin tags to check where they are.

Comment: So there is no specific reason?

Comment: My point is that absolute majority of other objects are placed correctly in the administrative divisions. For some reason specifically national parks are often are not placed.